# How to select all rows created in the last hour?

Tags: sql, postgresql

My query is

```
SELECT  * FROM email_operation WHERE cdate = CURRENT_DATE  and ctime  >= (NOW() - INTERVAL '1 hour' )
```

to select all rows created at the last hour but it doesn't work. It throws an error at `>=`

```
SELECT  * FROM email_operation WHERE cdate = CURRENT_DATE  and ctime  >= (NOW() - INTERVAL '12 hour' )
> ERROR:  operator does not exist: time without time zone >= timestamp with time zone
LINE 1: ..._operation WHERE cdate = CURRENT_DATE  and ctime  >= (NOW() ...
                                                             ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

> Time: 0.001s
```

Comment: Please show the data types you are dealing with.  Sample data and desired results also help.

Comment: What's the data type of `ctime`?

Comment: @TheImpaler the type of `ctime` is time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
where (cdate + ctime)::timestamp(0) >= (now() - interval '1 hour')
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently `ctime` is a `time` column, so you can't compare it with a timestamp (which is what the error message tells you). You need to use `current_time` instead:

```
and ctime >= current_time - interval '1 hour'
```

Note that this won't work properly around midnight.

It seems you have split up date and time into two columns (which is a bad idea), but you can combine them to compare a timestamp:

```
and cdate + ctime >= current_timestamp - interval '1 hour'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want results in the past hour and you have separated the date and time components, then one method is:

```
WHERE (cdate + ctime) >= NOW() - INTERVAL '1 hour'
```

Note that this will even work between midnight and 1:00 a.m.  Sadly, it probably won't use indexes.  That might be an issue if you have lots of data.  Here is one method that will at least use an index on `cdate`:

```
WHERE cdate IN (CURRENT_DATE, CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '1 day') AND
      ( (cdate + ctime) >= NOW() - INTERVAL '1 hour' )
```